# How to get the v-model of component that called the function in Vuetify?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I happen to do the form in which each text-field has to cooperate with each other for example:

```
<template>
 <v-app>
  <v-text-field v-model="foo1" @input="updateForm">
  <v-text-field v-model="foo2" @input="updateForm">
 </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {foo1:0, foo2:0}
 },

 methods:{
  updateForm(foo){
   foo1=foo1/foo1+foo2
   foo2=foo2/foo1+foo2

   //Can we get the v-model of foo which called the function to make a special update?? like 
   // foo=foo/2
 } 

 }
}
</script>
```

Im using Vue2

Comment: pass them in as you would a normal JS function call in your template code, e.g. `@input="updateForm(foo1)"` and `@input="updateForm(foo2)"` for each of your v-text-fields.

Comment: @yoduh that not working the received variable contain just value of foo not the actual foo v-model. So when the function gose foo="something" it not update foo1 or foo2

Comment: It's not possible to pass the v-model variable by reference to a method, the best you can do is send some kind of identifier that your method can use to figure out which variable has been updated.  I've posted an answer with such a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array to hold all the values of your inputs and passing the array index to the event handler method is the most common way of solving your problem.  With an array you can also utilize [v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html) to dynamically render your input elements, which cuts down on duplicate code.

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-text-field 
      v-for="(foo, i) in foos" :key="i" 
      type="number"
      v-model.number="foos[i]"
      @input="updateForm(i)"
    />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foos: [0, 0]
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateForm(fooIndex) {
      this.foos[fooIndex] += 1;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```